# Does cloning a repo using Github CLI use HTTPS or SSH?

Tags: git, github, git-clone, github-cli

I am a member of a GitHub org that requires pushes to be done through SSH, so when I clone down repos I need to use the syntax `git clone git@github.com:<ORG>/<REPO>.git`.

I am migrating over to using the GitHub CLI more and more now, and have just noticed the new(ish) option on GitHub to "Clone with GitHub CLI" (`gh repo clone <ORG>/<REPO>`). Does this use SSH or HTTPS to clone? As far as I can tell, [the official docs](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_clone) don't specify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further digging shows that [the default `git_protocol` is HTTPS](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_config).

You can override this to use ssh by default with `gh config set git_protocol ssh` and check that it has worked by viewing the output of `gh config get git_protocol`.